# Watch environment variable in C

Tags: environment-variables

How can I watch an environment variable for changes in C? Judging by [the GLIbc manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_mono/libc.html#Environment-Access), I don't think there's a standard way to do this, but I just want to be sure. I'm looking for something like this:

```
void watchenv(char *varname, void(callback*)());
```

Comment: You can't, when a process is started it gets a _copy_ of its parent's environment. Any changes made by the parent aren't propagated to its children (and vice versa). What do you want to accomplish?

Comment: @robertklep ok, thanks. I thought this was like a way to store variables that every program could access at the same time. Is there anything else that maches that description (on GNU/POSIX systems)?

Comment: The Unix environment is customarily an argument at exec time and won't respond to subsequent alterations in your shell. Traditionally this problem would be solved by rereading a config file on SIGHUP, but I don't know what people like to do these days.

Comment: Rereading a config file on reception of a signal as suggested by @DavidEisenstat is quite a common solution (still). I don't think POSIX or common libc implementations offer a specific file format parser interface for that though, so that's something you have to think about yourself.

Comment: Please modify your question to better explain the behavior of your hypothetical `watchenv()` function. Env vars are private to each process. Are you asking for a way to track changes to the env vars of the current process or an arbitrary process? The latter is, essentially, impossible. the former is theoretically possible but not possible in practice since it would require using a mechanism like `LD_PRELOAD` to intercept the calls to the functions that modify the process env vars.

Comment: Addendum to my previous comment... You can't even reliably track changes to the env vars of the current process without using debugger magic since a process can modify the value of an env var by directly modifying the location of the env var without using a function like `putenv` or `setenv`. What are you really trying to do and why?

Comment: @KurtisRader I wasn't aware of how environment functions actually worked. I thought they were global system variables, and I wanted to use them as a way to change the behaviour of a library during runtime. I know that it can't be done this way now.